# How to use scrolltop for element inside an overflown element

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="inner">
some stuff
</div>
</div
```

The wrapper has `overflow-y:scroll` and a fixed height, equal to `window.height()`.

I want to trigger an action using `scrolltop` for the inner element, for example, after the inner element scrolls 20 pixels, but `scrolltop` doesn't seem to work because of the overflown element. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Umm... `window.height` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aQAvE/

```
if ( $(this).scrollTop() == "50" )
```

Change the number here to suite your needs

Comment: thanks a lot! Sometimes you are thinking so complex that easy stuff evade you!